# How to detect device is tablet or foldable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to determine if device is tablet or foldable or phone.
I am using the following code to define the tablet:

```
public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
        boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
        return (xlarge || large);
    }
```

I tested this code on several devices, it worked correctly. But I'm still not sure that this is a hundred percent working option.

But I have another problem. I have not found a way to determine foldable devices.

Is it possible to determine whether the device is foldable or not?

Comment: This article might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/make-apps-fold-aware.  The article also links to this: [interface FoldingFeature extends DisplayFeature](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/window/layout/FoldingFeature)

Comment: Try this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowMetrics

Answer (score 1):

To make your app fold aware, use [Jetpack Window Manager](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/window), a library that provides a common API surface for different window features, like folds or a hinge. When your app is fold aware, the content in the window can be adapted to avoid folds and hinges or to take advantage of them and use them as natural separators.

It has now support for folding phones through WindowInfoTracker and FoldingFeature. WindowMetricsCalculator to help calculate the current WindowMetrics.

Add this dependency
  `implementation "androidx.window:window:1.0.0"`

```
class DisplayFeaturesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDisplayFeaturesBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityDisplayFeaturesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                WindowInfoTracker.getOrCreate(this@DisplayFeaturesActivity)
                    .windowLayoutInfo(this@DisplayFeaturesActivity)
                    .collect { newLayoutInfo ->
                        // Use newLayoutInfo to update the layout.
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @famfamfam No issues man.> do upvote if this helped you and let me know if you're stuck anywhere